# Yii2 Cross-Origin Request Blocked WITH ANGULAR2

Tags: rest, angular, yii, yii2

Am using angular2 and yii2 restful services but it fails
In yii2 controller i have set

```
    public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
     $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
        'cors' => [
            // restrict access to
            'Origin' => ['http://localhost:4200'],  //this is my angular2 source
            'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['POST', 'GET','PUT', 'OPTIONS'],
            // Allow only POST and PUT methods
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
            // Allow only headers 'X-Wsse'
            // 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
            // Allow OPTIONS caching
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 3600,
            // Allow the X-Pagination-Current-Page header to be exposed to the browser.
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => ['X-Pagination-Current-Page'],
        ],
    ];

    $auth = $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
        'only' => ['can-access','profile'],  //access controller
    ];

   $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options'];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

In angular2 am setting the headers as

```
  get(url) {
let headers = new Headers();
let token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")).token;
if (token) {
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
}

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.get(url, {headers:headers});
```

}

when i check a post request am getting an error that

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows 
reading the remote resource at     
 http://127.0.0.1/bcl/api/rest/v1/users/profile.
  (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).
```

Internet search i found out that i needed to set the cors filters as above but still it fails

Comment: Can you show the request and response headers for your request from the browser network tab.

Answer (score 0):

As your error states, the browser sent a preflight request, got a list of allowed Origins( in your case it is 'http://localhost:4200') and devided to block your request.

Your request is at "http://127.0.0.1/bcl/api/rest/v1/users/profile" when your Allowed origin is set to "http://localhost:4200".

Change

```
'Origin' => ['http://localhost:4200'],
```

to

```
'Origin' => ['http://127.0.0.1'],
```

Answer (score 0):

`'Origin' => ['http://localhost:4200'],`

to

`'Origin' => ['*'],`